# Show $x^3-nx+2$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I am asked to show that $x^3-nx+2$ is irreducible if $n\neq -1, 3, 5$.

I proved a similar problem before, where I was asked to show that the polynomial 
$f(x)=x^3+nx-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ if $n\neq 1, -3, -5$. (Proof below)

$Proof:$ Let $p(x)=x^3+nx+2$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and suppose that $p(x)$ is 
reducible. By the rational root test, a root $a$ of $p(x)$ must be
$a=\pm1, \pm 2$.

If $p(1)=0$, then $1^3+n(1)+2=0\implies n=-3$.

If $p(-1)=0$, then $(-1)^3-n+2=0\implies n=1$.

If $p(2)=0$, then $(2)^3+2n+2=0\implies n=-5$.

If $p(-2)=0$, then $(-2)^3-2n+2\implies n=-3$.

Therefore, if $n\neq1,-3,-5$, then $p(x)$ is irreducible.

My question is, how should I go about this proof differently than the previous one, since I do not know what field I am factoring over? (i.e. I do not think I can use the rational root test because we are not necessarily factoring over $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$?)

This question is from Dummit and Foote's algebra book, section 13.1 question 7  by the way.

Comment: I would guess you are indeed factoring over $\mathbb{Q}$. When the field is not stated, it's generally assumed to be $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise Thanks, I didn't know that- however it seems strange to me that the proof I have completed would be in the exercises in chapter 7.5, and the proof I am stuck on wouldn't come up until chapter 13.1

Comment: Since a polynomial is monic, its content is 1. Hence irreducible over Q iff irreducible over Z. From the exercise in the book it is to be understood that we are thinking of irreducibility over Q

Comment: The irreducibility is over $\Bbb{Q}$ because a cubic equation (over $\Bbb{Q}$) is always reducible over $\Bbb{R}$ for it has a real root.